# Why do sometimes you have to create a new list and sometimes you don't in Unity?

Tags: list, unity-game-engine

So I upgraded a project into another.

In the first project, prefabs were already in the scene, and I manually set up all the components and scripts on them.

In the second one, prefabs were created by script at runtime and I had to add everything through script.

I didn't have much trouble until I got to a script which had a public list. When the code ran it gave me a null reference everytime the list was called.

So after digging and trials and error, I found out that instead of just declaring the list (public List whatever;) I had to instantiate it (public List whatever = new List).

I'm happy I found a solution, **but I don't understand it** and it's bugging me. Why did I have to create a new list in the second project?

Comment: Good practice is to not rely on the state of a prefab, but to always initialize is manually. For me, I try to put as little as I can in the Start() method, and I usually write an Initialize(...) method that allows me to set up the prefab. This is lets you have full control over how the prefab is set up, but more importantly, the order in which they are set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you manually add a script to a game object in Unity editor, Unity will initialize that public List to an empty List. It will then serialize that empty List. When you instantiate a manually created prefab, it will already contain that empty List that the editor serialized.

Comment: You can say in general the Unity Editor automatically initializes any serialized field. `public` properties are automatically serialized but this also applies to `[SerialzeField] private List<T> ` as long as it is somewhere used in the inspector. The same counts for arrays as well.

Comment: And just for a complete info: value type fields (int, bool, string, float etc) are allways initialized with a default value even if they are private ;)

Answer (score 1):

Declaring List means that the class that you created have a List but it still does not have a value by default. In order for the List to be usable, you have to create an instance of it by assigning `= new List<Data>`.

Answer (score 0):

its the difference between saying you have a picture(reference) or your at the place, (instance) think of it this way. lets say that list wasnt a list, it was just an int.

i can say 
`int i;`

and i have a reference, but the reference is empty, i.e. it has no value.

but if i say 
`int i = 0;`

it now has value, without the zero i cant act on `i` because the computer dosnt know what do do with it....

so basicaly saying `List<Item> list;`

and not List list = `new List<Item>()`

means you have declared that variable, and allocated space in memory, but it dosnt mean anything, until you assign a value. hope this helps.

You cannot use uninitialized variables in C#. You can initialize a variable with the default value of its type. You also can use the default value of a type to specify the default value of a method's optional argument.

Comment: `int i;` works just fine because it is a *value type.* It is automatically assigned a default value (of 0).

Comment: `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0165 Use of unassigned local variable 'i'     `    it does?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default-values-table   check it out. yeah it has a value, but it wont compile unless its assigned!

Comment: still need to call it as default, i.e. `int a = default(int);` or the default literal `int a = default;`  but thats just overly complicated when `int a = 0` is less to type

Comment: The asker is not using a *local* variable. *`a script which had a public list`*, public fields in scripts are automatically assigned a value during Unity's serialization process. See Shapov's answer. Private fields are also assigned default values (and only throw a **warning** when compiled). `warning CS0649: Field 'Temp.i' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value '0'`.

Comment: @Vanethrane Draco18 is right: your post applies to local variables within a method but not to members/properties of a class. There any value type field will be initialized  automatically  with default values if not initialized yet. Reference type fields only if they are serialized.